# Python get generated url to string

Tags: python, string, url, geturl

(Title might change not too sure what to call it)

So I'm trying to open a URL that directs to a random page
(This URL: http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&do.random=1)
and I want to return where that URL goes

```
    randomURL = urllib.urlopen("http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&do.random=1")
    print(randomURL)
```

That's what I (stupidly) thought would work. I imported urllib

Comment: Yes I am using Python3

Comment: So you want to detect what URL a different URL gets redirected to? Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3 >, `urllib.urlopen` was replaced by `urllib.request.urlopen`. Change the request line to this:

```
urllib.request.urlopen('http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&do.random=1')
```

For more, you can see the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html)

But if you want to have the url, which is a bit more difficult, you can take a look at [`urllib.request.HTTPRedirectHandler`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.request.html?highlight=httpredirecthandler#urllib.request.HTTPRedirectHandler)

Comment: The questioner wants to get the final URL (ie the URL that is redirected to).